# Clojure OAuth 2 server libraries

Tags: oauth, clojure, oauth-2.0

Are there any Clojure libraries that help create OAuth 2 service providers? What do you use to provide third party clients authorization? What do you use to authorize JavaScript front end of your web service?

Answer (score 0):

[Friend](https://github.com/cemerick/friend) has an OAuth2 implementation if you've not seen it. [Here's an example project](https://github.com/ddellacosta/friend-oauth2-examples/blob/master/src/friend_oauth2_examples/google_handler.clj) using OAuth2 as well. It's slightly old (about a year) but [here's a discussion](https://github.com/cemerick/friend/issues/117) of how somebody else implemented it in August.

Comment: Hi Oliver, thanks for reply. I've seen and used Friend, but it has only OAuth2 client implementation. Maybe the question isn't clear, but what I need is authentication server implementation (service provider) in Clojure. I've seen clauth (https://github.com/pelle/clauth) but it was last updated a year ago.

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice article touching on how to implement something yourself:

https://leonid.shevtsov.me/en/oauth2-is-easy

Seems protocol isn't too complicated to implement from scratch.

Comment: That article is for OAuth client, not service provider as OP requested.